# How to reconcile Rust Mutex and (C) caller supplied locking mechanisms?

Tags: c, rust, mutex

I'm writing a PKCS#11 library  in Rust and I'm running into some trouble with how to reconcile caller supplied locking mechanisms i.e. CreateMutex, DestroyMutex, LockMutex, UnlockMutex with Rust's implementation of mutexes.

Mutexes in C, are of course, not tied to data. They simply set a lock over a section and the programmer is responsible for the creation/destruction and locking/unlocking of the mutexes. Whereas, Rust does tie data to the mutex itself.

How can I reconcile both cases: when supplied locking mechanisms from the calling program (not tied to data and manually create/lock/unlock/destroy) vs no locking mechanisms are supplied and to use Rust locking (tied to data and MutexGuard and scoped dropping/unlocking of mutex)?

Should I use parking_lot::Mutex with the raw_lock/raw_unlock to make the patterns similar e.g. not tied to data?

Comment: Usually spinlocks are used to protect the data, not mutexes

Comment: @tstanisl Can you explain to me how a spinlock would address my question?

Comment: You *could* have the mutex as `Mutex<()>`, and have your data separate (probably in an `UnsafeCell`) and ensure the protection manually. Though I'm unfamiliar with PKCS#11 so there might be a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "when supplied locking mechanisms from the calling program". Are you writing a function that takes a particular kind of mutex and is expected to lock it internally?

Comment: Note that *all* mutexes are tied in some way to shared data - if there's no data to share, there's no need for a lock. It's not always obvious in a C program exactly *what* data is guarded by a particular lock, and that data may be too obscure or distributed to put in a single container - but that doesn't mean the mutex doesn't guard any data. This may contribute to my confusion over "supplied locking mechanisms" - anyone who provides you with a locking mechanism should *tell* you what it guards and how to use it, and you're beholden to their requirements

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution; it's not pretty but it works and passes the miri test. The general idea is we bundle a `Mutex<()>` and an optional `MutexGuard` for that mutex.  I did not add proper handling of errors or naming to match the standard.

The structs:

```rust
struct MutexContainer {
    mutex: Mutex<()>,
    guard: Cell<Option<MutexGuard<'static, ()>>>,
}
pub struct OpaqueMutex {
    _data: [usize;0],
}
```

Note that `OpaqueMutex` is simply an opaque handle to avoid leaking the internals of the `MutexContainer`, as is best practice during ffi. The key thing with this design is that the struct cannot move if it holds a guard.

Mutex creation:

```rust
pub unsafe extern "C" fn create_mutex(mutex: *mut *mut OpaqueMutex) -> libc::c_ulong {
    *mutex = Box::into_raw(Box::new(
        MutexContainer {
            mutex: Mutex::new(()),
            guard: Cell::new(None),
        },
    ))
    .cast();
    0
}
```

Nothing fancy going on here, just leaking the mutex on the heap.

Mutex locking:

```rust
pub unsafe extern "C" fn lock_mutex(mutex: *mut OpaqueMutex) -> libc::c_ulong {
    let container:&MutexContainer = &*mutex.cast();
    let lock:MutexGuard<'static, _> = mem::transmute(container.mutex.lock().unwrap());
    container.guard.set(Some(lock));
    0
}
```

Here I use `mem::transmute` to lengthen the lifetime of the lock and store the result. The `transmute` is safe because we ensure that we don't move its parent mutex and we don't let it outlive the mutex here or elsewhere. The mutex will remain locked until the guard is dropped.

Mutex unlocking:

```rust
pub unsafe extern "C" fn unlock_mutex(mutex: *mut OpaqueMutex) -> c_ulong{
    let container:&MutexContainer = &*mutex.cast();
    if container.mutex.try_lock().is_ok(){
        return !0; //can't unlock an unlocked mutex
    } else {
        container.guard.set(None);
    }
    0
}
```

Here we use the nonblocking `try_lock` to determine if the mutex is locked. If `try_lock` succeeds that means the mutex is unlocked and we return an error. Otherwise, we drop the guard by overwriting it with `None`.

Mutex drop:

```rust
pub unsafe extern "C" fn drop_mutex(mutex: *mut OpaqueMutex) -> c_ulong{
    unlock_mutex(mutex);
    drop(Box::from_raw(mutex.cast::<MutexContainer>()));
    0
}
```

Here we ensure the mutex is unlocked to prevent a dangling reference by the guard and then reclaim the memory by reboxing the pointer.

[Full playground link plus test harness.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7995b2ce883d68ef19e06ffc595c365)

Disclaimer: while this code passes miri, it is far from production-ready: there is basically no error handling. You should make sure that errors are handled robustly and sanity checks (like null and alignment checks) are made, especially since you are implementing a crypto library.

edit: the example main program invoked undefined behavior by erroneously locking the mutex outside of the new threads unlocking them inside the threads, rather than locking the mutex within each thread and unlocking them when done. Not sure why I thought that was a good idea.